# css :pseudo-class for increasing the specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

Is there a **pseudo class** with **minimal characters** that virtually **always match** to everything?

Right now I'm using `nth-child(n)`, but i'm not quite happy because **the characters are too much**.
Or use a real class `:not(._)`.

Can you suggest me the better options?

I want to use it just for increasing the specificity. Here the illustration:

```
/* the specificity index is [0,5,0] */
:nth-first-child(2n+3):nth-child(n):nth-child(n):nth-child(n):nth-child(n) {
   color: 'red',
}
```

NOTE:

- do not use `!important` because the rule become too difficult be overwritten later.
- do not use #idfoo because the id specificity is one magnitude greater than (pseudo) class or attr selector, so it become too difficult be overwritten.

Why I do this?
Because i'm making a css library that some **state classes** like `.enabled`, `.active`, `.engaged`, `.excited` must be more dominant than **variant classes** like `.big`, `.dark`, `.mini`.
All the dominant & non dominant classes should be easily overridden later.

Comment: What is the usecase for this? I am instinctively horrified because that sounds like a good way to make the code an unreadable mess.

Comment: Artificially increasing the specificity is almost as bad as using !important. You should look into what elements you really want to target and override just the rules that are already in place for those elements.

Comment: i want to define a selector that overwrites the other selectors but still be able be overwritten by another sub-sub-components

Comment: am making a `css builder` in javascript something like this: `defineRule([':disabled', '.enabled', '.excited'], { color: 'black' }, { minSpecificity: 3 })` then rendered to `:is(:disabled, :enabled, .excited):nth-child(n):nth-child(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not(#_)`. An ID selector is stronger than classes or `:nth-child()`

```css
h1:not(#_) {
  color:blue;
}

h1.title {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">text</h1>
```

Comment: the id selector is stronger but it will hard to re-overwritten on the sub-sub component. I am making a css lib that allow to be overwritten further.